# Undefined variable after using require_once

Tags: php

I have created a Page class and all the pages on my website are objects of that Page class. Each Page object has a title attribute which is passed in as an argument to the constructor and so creating a new Page object looks as follows.

```
<?php

require_once('library/Page.php');

$page = new Page('About');

$page->header();
```

This is where the problem arises.

The header() method is...

```
public function header()
{   

    require_once($this->templatePath . 'header.php');

}
```

I then echo the page title using

```
<?php echo $page->title; ?>
```

However, I get the following error.

> **Notice**:  Undefined
>   variable: page in
>   **/Users/aaronfalloon/Projects/PHP/tfm/template/header.php**
>   on line **19**
>  
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property
>   of non-object in
>   **/Users/aaronfalloon/Projects/PHP/tfm/template/header.php**
>   on line **19**

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose a class that none of us have seen. Show us what's going on within your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me further explain about what Gumbo has written.

When you included the template file, you did the operation WITHIN the header function, thus making all $page variable in the template file referring to the local $page variable in the header function, which apparently is not declared/defined.

You should use $this->title instead to refer to the current class.

It is something like

```
class Page{

  public function header(){
    echo $this->title;
  }

}
```

when you try to include the template file:

```
// page class
class Page{

  public function header(){
    include('template.php');
  }

}
```

.

```
// template file
echo $this->title;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$this->title` instead of `$page->title` since you refer to the property of the very same instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, it may be possible to solve this issue by adding `global $page;` before the `require_once` call in your `Page::header` function.

The require_once includes the code of the specified file and execute it keeping the current scope. In your `Page::header` function, `$page` is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

`$page` is declared as a global and the header.php code has only local scope to the method.

Either:
Use `global $page` after the method declaration before the `require_once`.
Pass `$page` into the header function as an argument `public function header($page)`.
Use `echo $this->title` in header.php.

Or if you really want to screw around use `extract(get_object_vars($this))` and `echo $title`.